# Question about how to apply the result of useQuery to defaultValues ​of useForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-query

hello awesome developers !

i have a question

The values ​​imported by useQuery are values ​​that can be undefined, so they cannot be applied to defaultValues. Does anyone know a good way?

Perhaps it should be something like this.

```
title: data.title
```

That is, there should be no question marks.

can i do this?

```
const { data: estimateData, isLoading: isEstimateDataLoading } = useQuery<EstimateRequire>([`getOneEstimate`, estimatePk, `estimate_detail`], getOneEstimate);
 
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, reset } = useForm<EstimateRequireForm>({
        // mode: "onSubmit",
        // estimatePk, title, product, manager, email, phone_number, content, estimate_require_completion, memo
        defaultValues: {
            title: estimateData?.title,
            product: estimateData?.product,
            email: estimateData?.email,
            manager: estimateData?.manager,
            phone_number: estimateData?.phone_number,
            content: estimateData?.content,
            estimate_require_completion: estimateData?.estimate_require_completion,
            memo: estimateData?.memo,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

`defaultValues` are only evaluated when the component mounts, similar to the default value of `useState`. It's not "reactive" - it doesn't change over time.

react-hook-form has a rather new approach to this - the `values` prop. From [the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform):

> The values props will react to changes and update the form values, which is useful when your form needs to be updated by external state or server data.

And the example is:

```
// set default value sync
function App({ values }) {
  useForm({
    values  // will get updated when values props updates       
  })
}

function App() {
  const values = useFetch('/api');
  
  useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    },
    values, // will get updated once values returns
  })
}
```